# Server not returning Stripe customer id to android app

Tags: java, php, android, client-server, web-hosting

Right now all I'm trying to do is use a Stripe token I have created in the android activity below, send it to my server (see php script below), and then return the customer id to me and print it in an alertdialogue box.

Right now when I plug in correct and working VISA test card number 4242424242424242 with a future exp date and cvc 991 all the app does is show my created Stripe token in the Toast dialogue and then in the alertdialogue it just shows the title "Customer ID".

I use the backgroundWorker class to communicate to my server and believe the issue must be in there.  Does anything look strange?

Even when I have the php file only echo "Hello" is doesn't show up in alertdialogue, is there something wrong with how I am communicating with my server?

I am webhosting on GoDaddy and bought zeuspower.xyz today and have createCus.php file in /home/zeuspower/public_html folder:
[image]

Here is error:

```
02-04 18:21:16.147 10854-11059/com.zeuspwr.zeuspower W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://zeuspower.xyz/createCus.php
02-04 18:21:16.147 10854-11059/com.zeuspwr.zeuspower W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:186)
02-04 18:21:16.147 10854-11059/com.zeuspwr.zeuspower W/System.err:     at com.zeuspwr.zeuspower.backgroundWorker.doInBackground(backgroundWorker.java:52)
02-04 18:21:16.147 10854-11059/com.zeuspwr.zeuspower W/System.err:     at com.zeuspwr.zeuspower.backgroundWorker.doInBackground(backgroundWorker.java:22)
02-04 18:21:16.147 10854-11059/com.zeuspwr.zeuspower W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
02-04 18:21:16.147 10854-11059/com.zeuspwr.zeuspower W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
02-04 18:21:16.147 10854-11059/com.zeuspwr.zeuspower W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
02-04 18:21:16.147 10854-11059/com.zeuspwr.zeuspower W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
02-04 18:21:16.147 10854-11059/com.zeuspwr.zeuspower W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
02-04 18:21:16.147 10854-11059/com.zeuspwr.zeuspower W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

backgroundWorker class:

```
public class backgroundWorker extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{

    Context context;
    AlertDialog alertDialog;
    backgroundWorker(Context ctx){
        context = ctx;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        String type = params[0];
        String createCus_url = "http://zeuspower.xyz/createCus.php";
        if(type.equals("createCustomer")){
            try {
                String email = params[2];
                String stripeToken = params[1];
                URL url = new URL(createCus_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
                String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("email","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(email,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                        URLEncoder.encode("stripeToken","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(stripeToken,"UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
                String result="";
                String line="";
                while ((line=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
                    result+=line;
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return result;
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Customer ID");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        alertDialog.setMessage(result);
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }
}
```

Android Activity:

```
public class newUser extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText fNameh, lNameh, emailh, phoneNumh, pinh, cardNumberh, cardCVCh;
    Spinner cardExpMonthh, cardExpYearh;
    String fname, lname, email, phonenum, pin, cardNumber, cardCVC, cardExpMonthStr, cardExpYearStr;
    Integer cardExpMonth, cardExpYear;
    String stripetok;
    Card cardNew;

    private static final String PUBLISHABLE_KEY = "pk_test_iUVdhdvJuurqSxIlXpzq32LS";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_user);

        fNameh = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fNameNew);
        lNameh = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lNameNew);
        emailh = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailNew);
        phoneNumh = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phoneNew);
        pinh = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pinNew);
        cardNumberh = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cardNumNew);
        cardCVCh = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cvcNew);
        cardExpMonthh = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.monthNew);
        cardExpYearh = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.yearNew);
        ImageButton createNewUser = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.createNew);



        createNewUser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {

                fname = fNameh.getText().toString();
                lname = lNameh.getText().toString();
                email = emailh.getText().toString();
                phonenum = phoneNumh.getText().toString();
                pin = pinh.getText().toString();
                cardNumber = cardNumberh.getText().toString();
                cardCVC = cardCVCh.getText().toString();
                cardExpMonthStr = cardExpMonthh.getSelectedItem().toString();
                cardExpYearStr = cardExpYearh.getSelectedItem().toString();
                cardExpMonth = Integer.valueOf(cardExpMonthStr);
                cardExpYear = Integer.valueOf(cardExpYearStr);




                //create card for Stripe token
                cardNew = new Card(
                        cardNumber,
                        cardExpMonth,
                        cardExpYear,
                        cardCVC
                );

                if(cardNew.validateCard() & cardNew.validateCVC()) {
                    final Stripe stripe = new Stripe();
                    stripe.createToken(cardNew, PUBLISHABLE_KEY, new TokenCallback() {
                        public void onSuccess(Token token) {

                            String stripeToken = token.getId();
                            String type = "createCustomer";

                            //MySQL database start
                            backgroundWorker bwork = new backgroundWorker(newUser.this);
                            bwork.execute(type,stripeToken, email);

                            // TODO: Send Token information to your backend to initiate a charge
                            Toast.makeText(
                                    getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Token created: " + token.getId(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                        public void onError(Exception error) {
                            Log.d("Stripe", error.getLocalizedMessage());
                        }
                    });

                }

                else{
                    Toast.makeText(
                            getApplicationContext(),
                            "Token not made!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }



                /*Intent retPage = new Intent(BorroworReturn.this, returno.class);

                startActivity(retPage);*/
            }
        });
    }

}
```

PHP Code:

```
// Set your secret key: remember to change this to your live secret key in production
// See your keys here: https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("My Secret API");

// Token is created using Stripe.js or Checkout!
// Get the payment token submitted by the form:
$token = $_POST['stripeToken'];

// Create a Customer:
$customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
  "email" => $email,
  "source" => $token,
));

// Charge the Customer instead of the card:
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
  "amount" => 1000,
  "currency" => "usd",
  "customer" => $customer->id
));

// YOUR CODE: Save the customer ID and other info in a database for later.
$newCustID = $customer->id;
echo .$newCustID;
//echo "Hi";
?>
```

Comment: Could it be because my site isn't up and running yet? Like when you go to zeuspower.xyz nothing actually loads yet as I haven't finished the site.  Right now all I'm trying to do is see how to create customers.